# Laravel error model using function attributesToArray with created_at

Tags: php, laravel-4, models

I'm trying to clone a model using the function attributesToArray; but, I've got a problem with dates `created_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000'`.

This is my code:

```
$user2 = new User2(); 
$user2->fill($user->attributesToArray());
```

Exception returns me the message:

> InvalidArgumentException Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is change the model:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array();
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators